# Why does this not want to find the selector on dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the below select to choose a second form to pull in via `load()` into the `#formContent` `div` which works fine.

```
<form id="selectform">
    <select id="selector" class="form-control" name="selector">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose your Poison</option>
        <option value="website">Website</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="formContent"> </div>
```

The form that gets pulled in is:

```
<form id="website">
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" data-path="name">
    </div>
</form>
```

Once loaded, any inputs in the second form should have a listener attached via `keyup`, which also seems to be fine.

On `keyup` we do indeed get into the `keyup` function, however we are not getting past the `$input.each()` function and the data-path attribute is not being seen.

In the `console.log` output, we get to "1. got here", but not to "2. got here".

I have tried numerous things, to no avail. Can anyone spot what the heck is going on here?

jQuery in use is 1.11.3

```
var mySelector, days = [];
$('#selector').on('change', function() {
    var theType = $(this).val();
    if(theType != ''){
        $('#formContent').load('forms/' + theType + '.html');
        var mySelector = '#' + theType;
        var element = {}, $input = $(mySelector + ' input,' + mySelector + ' textarea,' + mySelector + ' select');
        $(document).on('keyup', $input, function() {
            // WE GET THIS FAR
            console.log('1. got here.');
            element = {};
            $input.each(function(e) {
                console.log('2. got here.');
                if ($(this).data('path')) {
                    console.log('3. got here. ' + $(this).data('path'));
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the output of `console.log($input.length);` is at the point where the program appears to stop?

Comment: `input,` remove `,` try it should be `input#id` or `textarea#id`

Comment: If you could make a JS FIddle to replicate the problem it'd help get a better idea what's going on. It does look like that jquery.load is not leveraging the completed callback in your implementation and there more the data isn't there yet when you start looking for it. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: The selector argument for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is a string not a jQuery object.

Comment: Th event delegation way

`$(document).on('keyup', $input, function() {} );` when you are selecting the elements directly is not correct. And when you make a change, you are binding a bunch of events on document each time you change. Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @mwilson spot on. If you can add that as an answer I will set it as the approved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're not using the `.load` complete function as a callback. Your code is finished before the data is present:

```
var mySelector, days = [];
$('#selector').on('change', function() {
    var theType = $(this).val();
    if(theType != ''){
        $('#formContent').load('forms/' + theType + '.html', function ( data ) { //data will be the response once completed. This is only needed if you need to do something with the response data
        var mySelector = '#' + theType;
        var element = {}, $input = $(mySelector + ' input,' + mySelector + ' textarea,' + mySelector + ' select');
        $(document).on('keyup', $input, function() {
            // WE GET THIS FAR
            console.log('1. got here.');
            element = {};
            $input.each(function(e) {
                console.log('2. got here.');
                if ($(this).data('path')) {
                    console.log('3. got here. ' + $(this).data('path'));
                }
            });
        });
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to  try to access the *loaded html* **after** the `load` operation is **complete**

You need to add this **html** in **"complete" call back**. Like the api reference. http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#formContent').load('forms/' + theType + '.html',function() {

// callback here will make sure the load is complete. 
});
```

Small snippet of the code.

```
$('#formContent').load('forms/' + theType + '.html',function() {
        var mySelector = '#' + theType;
        var element = {}, $input = $(mySelector + ' input,' + mySelector + ' textarea,' + mySelector + ' select');
        $(document).on('keyup', $input, function() {
            // WE GET THIS FAR
            console.log('1. got here.');
            element = {};
            $input.each(function(e) {
                console.log('2. got here.');
                if ($(this).data('path')) {
                    console.log('3. got here. ' + $(this).data('path'));
                }
            });
        });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks alvaro, @mwilson already pointed that out to me above, and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic content, you need to use the $('selector').on(), as in $("#PostItemContainer").on("click", ".postitem", function() {...});

Comment: live is removed in 1.11 and on is the preferred way.

Comment: This is bad advice as `.iive()` has been deprecated from jQuery is 1.7 and removed in 1.9. The link you provided even states this. Event Delegation should be used via `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: Updated my answer with using .on(). Didn't realize .live() was deprecated..